# SQL query to split a path into rows, each row starting from root

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to split a path into its components, with the full path of each component.  It's hard to describe the situation; my best analogy is a database describing a filesystem.

The filesystem is organized simultaneously as both a tree and a graph; that is, each directory has a primary parent, but we allow directories to have multiple parents.  (We are careful not to create cycles.)  A `directory` master table maps directory IDs (inodes) to directory statistics (name, date, type, permissions, status, etc.).  A `hierarchy` table maps each directory to its children, with a flag for `primary`.  A `paths` table contains a `path_id` for each unique path.

For example, `/usr/games/pong` is a link to `/usr/local/bin/pong`.  The latter is the primary path, with one `path_id`, the former is another path, which is not the primary, although `usr` may be the primary parent of `games`.

What I am trying to do: Given the `path_id` of some directory, I want the breadcrumbs of how the child was reached.  So, for `path_id=891578` for the directory at `/home/manny/bin/src/cpl/include/`, I need the following rows, so I can supply a link to each of the parents in the path:

```
full_path           inode path_id  name     type  full_name
------------------  ----- -------  -------  ----  ------------------
/3/                    3   800328  home      R    ROOT-Home
/3/170/               170  321370  manny     U    USER-Manny
/3/170/177/           177  182210  bin       B    USER-Binaries
/3/170/177/179/       179  199033  src       S    USER-Source Code
/3/170/177/179/64/     64  111975  cpl       C    SYSTEM-CPL Program
/3/170/177/179/64/66/  66  891578  include   C    SYSTEM-CPL Include
```

So far, I have a query that I find extremely complicated.  It works - mostly - but I'm looking for something much simpler.  Here's what I have:

```
-- Get the "breadcrumbs" for a directory, by path_id:
SELECT full_path, inode, paths.path_id, dir.name, dir.type, dir.full_name, lvl
FROM (SELECT inode, lvl, Sys_Connect_By_Path(inode, '/') || '/' full_path
    FROM (SELECT lvl, Regexp_Substr((SELECT path FROM paths WHERE path_id = :pathId),
                        '[^/]+', 1, lvl) inode FROM dual
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL lvl FROM dual CONNECT BY Level < 10) )
    START WITH lvl = 1 CONNECT BY lvl = PRIOR lvl + 1)
JOIN paths ON paths.path = full_path
JOIN directory dir cm ON dir.directory_id = inode
ORDER BY full_path ;
```

(I don't actually need the `full_path` or the level in the final query, I just have it here for illustration.)

Can anyone suggest something simpler?  I thought of a hierarchical query that pulls off one element of the path on each iteration, via something like `Regexp_Replace(prior full_path, '[^/]+/$')`, but I can't get it working correctly.

An optimal solution would have as few bind variables as possible, and all done in a single query.  I am using Java (JDBC) to connect to an Oracle 12c database.

Other solutions have pointed out how to get each element on its own row; I am trying to get successive paths, each part of the original but starting at the beginning, each on its own row.

Thank you.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I don't want each element in its own row; I want the entire path to each element.

Comment: It appears your distinction between "primary" and "not primary" has no bearing on your question, right? (So then why even mention it?) Then - what do you mean by "I don't need the full_path" - it seems that's all you are talking about in the rest of the question. What DO you need? In particular, do you need to link back to the `paths` table to retrieve the `path_id` for each piece of the original path?

Comment: @mathguy You're right, I guess the "primary" doesn't really have any bearing, but it is the case, so I was thinking along those lines.  As for the `full_path`, I meant that I don't need it as a column in the final result set, but I do need it for a `JOIN` to another table (`paths`), as well as for the `ORDER BY` to create the breadcrumb trail.